# Longest palindrome after swapping operation

Tags: strings, string-matching, longest-common-substring

I know that [Manacher's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring#Manacher%27s_algorithm) can be used to find the longest palindromic substring of a string in linear time.
But I want to find the longest palindromic substring after swapping any two indices once.

If I run a for loop twice in $O(n^2)$ to find all possible swaps and find the max of all formed strings I get the ans but in $O(n^3)$.
Is there a better way like $O(n)$?

Comment: How do you get $O(n^2)$?

Comment: I think i made a mistake. It will be n^3. Manachers algo on each possible string formed after a swap.